# Updating PHP to Gaurd Against Mayhem Malware

Tags: php, webserver, malware

How will making sure my PHP version is updated thwart the Mayhem Malware?

Will updating PHP on my Ubuntu server prevent the Mayhem Malware from being able to make it onto the server, prevent it from running, or something else?

Is there anything else I can do to safeguard against it?

Edit:
This is the most informational article I've found which describes Mayhem: https://www.virusbtn.com/virusbulletin/archive/2014/07/vb201407-Mayhem

Comment: Is nailing your server down with SELinux something that is in the scope of things you're willing to do?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz No - I would like to avoid using SELinux. I'm hoping that proper server configuration/updates and AppArmor will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I caught one of the PHP "droppers" in a WordPress-like honeypot. The attackers gained access by guessing a password - brute force guessing, no hacks.

The PHP is entirely ordinary. It does nothing out of the ordinary, it does not call `eval`, or `preg_replace` or even `base64_decode`. There's really nothing you can do at the PHP level to guard against the code in the "dropper".

If you can keep attackers from guessing your WordPress or Joomla or whatever password, and keep your whatever up-to-date, and get lucky by not having any hackable plugins or 3rd-party code installed, you should be able to avoid Mayhem.

Comment: Are you suggesting that there are no configuration parameters that can be changed in php.ini to help safeguard against "droppers"?  What about using disable_functions? I'd like to find a way to avoid Mayhem without depending on "getting lucky".

Comment: @Boundless - the code I got, which is identical to what Virus Bulletin reports (https://www.virusbtn.com/virusbulletin/archive/2014/07/vb201407-Mayhem) only uses simple PHP - fopen()/fclose() is about as exotic as it gets.  The dropper code does call system(), which runs a command via the shell, so you could potentially disable system(): http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/ Like I wrote above, the PHP it uses is nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

> Will updating PHP on my Ubuntu server prevent the Mayhem Malware from being able to make it onto the server, prevent it from running, or something else?

By my [reading of this](http://www.net-security.org/malware_news.php?id=2813) and a few other things, no.  Although PHP is used in the deployment, it is not a vulnerability in the PHP interpreter that's being targeted.  It *may* exploit [mistakes in specific PHP code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability#PHP) (e.g. Wordpress), but upgrading your interpreter won't fix that; those problems must be identified and fixed in the application code.  It sounds like it does target vulnerabilities in apache and nginx, but if so, it's unlikely that there are fixes for those yet.  There's nothing (explicit) on the [nginx news page](http://nginx.org/) or [apache vulnerabilities](http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html) page.